# How to solve Crystal Reports error: Unable to cast COM object of type?

Tags: crystal-reports

How to solve Crystal Reports error: Unable to cast COM object of type? My system is Windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

CR for VS runtime is set for your platform and not the OS.

So if the AppPool of your server is running in 32 bit mode then you need to install the 32 bit MSI, if IIS is in 64 bit mode then the 64 bit runtime needs to be installed.